I get strange values for the greek letter pi and the product Pi
The following code produces the similar two numbers twice because the two lines of code are similar:
281 and 28677
I don't know what are those values and where they come from.
In the log file there's no indication whatsoever about pi and Pi or about those values.
Please enlighten me.
Thank you.
Code
\documentclass[]{article}

\setlength\parindent{0in}

\begin{document}

\number\pi\, and \number\Pi \\

\the\pi\, and \the\Pi

\end{document}


\pi is basically defined by \mathchardef\pi="0119, and "0119 (hexadecimal) is 281.

and for the product Pi?  Please make your comment an answer and I will accept it. And thanks for your help.

Same: \Pi is not product (that would be \prod) but just an uppercase pi, and is defined as "7005, which converted in decimals is 28677. But I'm unsure on how to phrase the answer so I'll refrain from writing one. I'm sure smarter users will :-)

This is what I meant. I meant by the word produt pi with uppercase Pi. Nonetheless, your comments are helpful.

\pi and \Pi are instructions for typesetting the symbols in the current font setup - the numbers are internal aspects of that. Perhaps you could outline what you are trying to achieve: this feels like an 'XY' issue.

I wrote a simple macro that converts integer numbers to their absolute values. And then I had the fancy idea to typeset, and only typeset the greek letter pi, and Pi, and ask the function to calculate absolute value, which is complete nonsense. And I expected that the code throw an error message. Instead of that, it returned the two respective values. Then to make things short I had the idea to try with \number and with \the. They gave the same result. And I didn't know how to interpret those values. This is the whole story.
